ACCESS_TOKEN_SCOPE_INSUFFICIENT error with creating sheet using Google Sheets API
I've been making a program in python that is intended to crete a spreadsheet. whether the fuction returns.

<HttpError 403 when requesting
https://sheets.googleapis.com/v4/spreadsheets?fields=spreadsheetId&alt=json
returned "Request had insufficient authentication scopes.". Details:
"[{'@type': 'type.googleapis.com/google.rpc.ErrorInfo', 'reason':
'ACCESS_TOKEN_SCOPE_INSUFFICIENT', 'domain': 'googleapis.com',
'metadata': {'service': 'sheets.googleapis.com', 'method':
'google.apps.sheets.v4.SpreadsheetsService.CreateSpreadsheet'}}]">

code here:


import os.path

from google.auth.transport.requests import Request
from google.oauth2.credentials import Credentials
from google_auth_oauthlib.flow import InstalledAppFlow
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
from googleapiclient.errors import HttpError
SCOPES = ["https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets"]

def create(title):
  """
  Creates the Sheet the user has access to.
  Load pre-authorized user credentials from the environment.
  TODO(developer) - See https://developers.google.com/identity
  for guides on implementing OAuth2 for the application.
  """
  creds = None
  # The file token.json stores the user's access and refresh tokens, and is
  # created automatically when the authorization flow completes for the first
  # time.
  if os.path.exists("token.json"):
    creds = Credentials.from_authorized_user_file("token.json", SCOPES)
  # If there are no (valid) credentials available, let the user log in.
  if not creds or not creds.valid:
    if creds and creds.expired and creds.refresh_token:
      creds.refresh(Request())
    else:
      flow = InstalledAppFlow.from_client_secrets_file(
        "credentials.json", SCOPES
      )
      creds = flow.run_local_server(port=0)
    # Save the credentials for the next run
    with open("token.json", "w") as token:
      token.write(creds.to_json())
  # pylint: disable=maybe-no-member
  try:

    service = build("sheets", "v4", credentials=creds)
    spreadsheet = {"properties": {"title": title}}

    spreadsheet = (
        service.spreadsheets()
        .create(body=spreadsheet , fields="spreadsheetId")
        .execute()

    )

    print(f"Spreadsheet ID: {(spreadsheet.get('spreadsheetId'))}")
    return spreadsheet.get("spreadsheetId")
  except HttpError as error:
    print(f"An error occurred: {error}")
    return error


if __name__ == "__main__":
  # Pass: title
  create("mysheet1")

Why this error i got and how i overcome the issue?

It's an error connected with authorization process. Have you check google sheets documentation? https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/authorization https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/quickstart/python

This question is similar to: ACCESS_TOKEN_SCOPE_INSUFFICIENT error with updating sheet using google sheets api (python). If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.
